# Convert String to CGFloat

Tags: swift

How can I convert a String to a CGFloat?

I tried :

```
var string     = "132"
var stringChange     = CGFloat((string as NSString).floatValue)
```

But in Xcode 7 it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code runs fine with Xcode 7 here

Comment: Who down voted this? This thread is needed, because quite frankly it's stupid you can't just do `CGFloat(string)`

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
let cgFloat : CGFloat? = Double("1.49").map{ CGFloat($0) }
```

`cgFloat` is `nil` if the string couldn't be parsed

You can also use the version without `map`, which does exactly the same:

```
let cgFloat : CGFloat?
if let double = Double("1.49") {
    cgFloat = CGFloat(double)
} else {
    cgFloat = nil
}
```

Example:

```
let toCGFloat = { Double($0).map{ CGFloat($0) } }

toCGFloat("123")      // 123
toCGFloat("123.3")    // 123.3
toCGFloat("123.8326947239875")    // 123.8326947239875
```

You can change `Double` to `Float` and have a look how the values get inaccurate, that's the reason you should use `Double`.

Comment: CGFloat is a float on 32-bit systems and double on 64-bit systems. By creating a double and turning that into a CGFloat you are doing the job of a CGFloat, and incorrectly.

Comment: @Abizern what's the job of a CGFloat? In the case that CGFloat is 64 bits, this method will do fine. If a CGFloat is 32 bits, this method will use a few extra bits of memory, which is also fine. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var yourString     = "132.0"
var yourFloatvalueFromString = CGFloat(NumberFormatter().number(from: yourString)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Double first, then to CGFloat. That worked for me on Swift 5.

```
let string = "9000"
let double = Double(string)!
let cgFloat = CGFloat(double)
```

I'm not sure why it's this way. But I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The CGFloat type is a type that is dependent on whether the system being run on is 32 bit or 64 bit. Essentially - it's a float.

So turn the string into a float and then turn that into a CGFloat. However, when making these sorts of conversions, you need to be aware that not all strings can be turned into a float (and hence, into a CGFloat). So, a good solution would be to write a simple initialiser for a CGFloat from a String as such:

```
extension CGFloat {
    init?(_ str: String) {
        guard let float = Float(str) else { return nil }
        self = CGFloat(float)
    }
}
```

And this extension can be used as follows:

```
let f1 = CGFloat("123")    // => 123
let f2 = CGFloat("123.3")  // => 123.300003051758
let f3 = CGFloat("123a")   // => nil
```

Comment: That's not really correct: The type `Float` is defined as a typealias of `Float32` on 32 _and_ 64-bit systems. So in your code a number with say 15 digits (64bit) would get truncated to 7 digits (32bit) even though CGFloat would be able to store all 64 bits. That's why I used Double (typealias of Float64) in my code: On a 64bit system, Double=CGFloat, no problem; on a 32bit system, we provide CGFloat with a 64bit value, which then gets truncated because CGFloat=Float32 can only story 32 of the bits